# Loop through XML attributes and elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched most of the forums and can't find what I am looking for. I want to do the following:

XML file:

```
<vaardigheden>
 <vaardigheid soort="techniek">HTML/CSS</vaardigheid>
 <vaardigheid soort="techniek">PHP/MySQL</vaardigheid>
 <vaardigheid soort="techniek">Javascript</vaardigheid>
 <vaardigheid soort="Instrument">Drums</vaardigheid>
 <vaardigheid soort="Instrument">Gitaar</vaardigheid>
</vaardigheden>
```

I would like to loop through the attributes and elements and get this result:

Techniek

- HTML/CSS
- PHP/MySQL
- Javascript

Instrument

- Drums
- Guitar

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? Just need the basic understanding of looping through attributes and elements in this way with jQuery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Play with this. I will return http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VHEcC/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VHEcC/)

[image]

Using [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and each - NOTE the script will work on either a string as here or an ajaxed file.

```
var xml = '<vaardigheden> <vaardigheid soort="techniek">HTML/CSS</vaardigheid> <vaardigheid soort="techniek">PHP/MySQL</vaardigheid><vaardigheid soort="techniek">Javascript</vaardigheid><vaardigheid soort="Instrument">Drums</vaardigheid><vaardigheid soort="Instrument">Gitaar</vaardigheid></vaardigheden>',
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$vaardigheden = $xml.find( "vaardigheid" );
var currentSoort = "", content = $("#content");
$.each($vaardigheden,function(i,item) {
    var soort = $(this).attr('soort');
    if (soort != currentSoort) {
        content.append("<dt>"+soort+"</dt>");
        currentSoort = soort;
    }
    content.append("<dd>"+$(this).text()+"</dd>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>XML JQUERY Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  

    function parseXml(xml)
    { 
       var titles = [];
       var newL ; 
       $(xml).find("vaardigheid").each(function()
       {
           if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr("soort"), titles)==-1){//append new title
                newL = '<label>'+$(this).attr("soort")+'</label><br/>'; 
                var newList = '<ul id="' + $(this).attr("soort") + '" \><li>'+$(this).text()+'</li></ul>';   
                $("#output").append($(newL));
                $("#output").append($(newList));
                titles.push($(this).attr("soort"));
           }
           else{
                var newItem = '<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
                $("#"+$(this).attr("soort")).append($(newItem));
           }

       });

   }

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "myFile.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: parseXml
   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="output"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why old jQuery and why script in the body? And your output is illegal I get `id="techniek" '=""`

Comment: I get `id="techniek" '=""` - you mean `id="' + $(this).attr("soort") + '">`

Comment: @mplungjan You are right. Missed an extra ' character. I corrected it and moved script in the head. I usually use script in the body _'because user doesn’t have to wait for scripts'_ according to http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html, but in this case this is not important.